# What's the BGM in K-ON?

Tags: music, k-on

In the anime series K-ON! there is a BGM used quite frequently but I can't find it anywhere. It appears a lot throughout the anime but not in the movie. Here are some examples:

Season 1

- episode 8: 8:17 ~ 8:48
- episode 9: 10:47 ~ 11:16

Season 2

- episode 1: 14:20 ~ 15:55
- episode 2: 13:55 ~ 14:57

These are selected at random and the time might vary a bit depending where you watch it. The hyperlink: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ew48VGOQPZRzN4Zl8zUmVjYWs/view leads to google drive which has the BGM. The file is an abstract from season 2, episode 1. Please help me find this song.

Comment: The file you linked is currently set to private. Please modify your permissions accordingly to allow public access or host it on another venue.

Comment: sorry about that, try it now

Comment: could it be Pinch Daisuki? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tybHA2x-TFM

Comment: Yes! That's it!

Comment: if you want, you can put it in the answers and i can vote it up for reputation

Comment: thank you ʞɹɐzǝɹ for taking your time to attempt this question, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the BGM you're looking for is titled Pinch Daisuki, it's on album 
K-ON! Original Soundtrack, track #33

[youtube link K-ON! - Pinch Daisuki [EXTENDED]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tybHA2x-TFM)